# How to refresh the Browserfield

Tags: javascript, blackberry, refresh, browserfield

I am using a class in which I am loading some text and images in browser field by using html tags.Now I want to change the text dynamically, how to refresh the browser field once after loading the screen.

If I use onclick tag on html to detect the click event then How to use java scripts to do some functionality for that click event. I am using document.getElementById to change the styles which I am using in my broserfield. How to reload the browser field or java scripts to view the updates.

How to use executeScript() to execute the javascript, simply added the string executeScript("javascript:(function() { " + value +"})()"); Value is the string where i used document.getElementById to get the elemenet id. Its not working.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post a simplified example of what you're doing?

Comment: Hi Max,

Thanks for your reply. Actually I could execute the java script now. What I am doing is, I have 3 customized managers in which having some buttons in top and bottom manager, and there is a browser field in the middle manager where I am adding some text, buttons and images. Now for example in the top manager I have a button, If I click that button it should change the font size of the text in the browser field for that I have used java script and its working fine.

Comment: But now my problem is I have one more button in the browser field, how to detect the click event from browser field and where to add the java script function, what are all the properties I supposed to set to detect the click event and to run the javascript function.

"<div id=\"image_holder\"> 
" <a href=\"#\"> <img src=" + encodedStrforZoom + " alt=\"Click here to Zoom\" width=\"25\" height=\"25\" border=\"0\" class=\"btn onClick=\"window.demo.clickOnEnlarge() \"/>  </a>" "</div>"

Comment: Here encodedStrforZoom is the encoded string of image. Now If I click this button it should load a new screen in my blackberry app. Can you help me in this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! You could try to extend RenderingApplication and handle click there, see http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field/RenderingApplication.html#eventOccurred%28net.rim.device.api.browser.field.Event%29 and example http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Display_content_in_BB_Browser_field_565587_11.jsp

Answer (score 0):

```
BrowserField brawserField  = new BrowserField();
browserField.refresh();

use refresh method for refreshing the page.
```